# Why Won't My Hard Drive Mount?

Tags: partitioning, mount

I have a hard drive that used to be an external hard drive on a Windows machine.  It has since been extracted and is installed in my ubuntu machine as `/deve/sda`.

Before I reformat or repartition it, I want to mount it to see what's currently on it.

This is what I get when I run `lsblk -f /dev/sda`:

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
sda
└─sda1
```

And this is what I get from `fdisk -l /dev/sda`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD40EZRX-00S
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xdb4bf07b

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1         256 976746239 976745984 465.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I notice that it only has one partition, which is 10% the size of the whole disk.  I have no idea what might cause that.

I have created the directory `/mnt/a`.

When I try to mount the partition with the command command `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/a`, I get the error

```
FUSE exfat 1.3.0
ERROR: exFAT file system is not found.
```

I get the same message for the following commands:

- `sudo mount /dev/sda /mnt/a`
- `sudo mount -t exfat  /dev/sda1 /mnt/a`
- `sudo mount -t exfat  /dev/sda /mnt/a`

Am I doing anything wrong with the `mount` command?  Is there something wrong with the disk / partition?

Comment: did you install the requisite libs for exfat?  they dont come preinstalled.

Comment: I installed exfat-fuse and exfat-utils

Comment: You show MBR(msdos) partitioning. With a drive over 2TiB, you must use gpt partitioning. Conversion MBR to gpt will erase drive, normally. Be sure to have good backups. Is NTFS partition hibernated? Windows normally leaves its partitions with fast start up on which sets hibernation flag. https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: I don't want to erase the drive until I find out what's on it.

That's why I'm trying to mount it.